# New to Selenium and maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have started new selenium project, which was created using Maven, when i Import it i get below error : Missing artifact com.openbet.testautomation.core:testautomation-core:jar:1.3.7-SNAPSHOT.
 Not sure how to fix it as the guy who designed it does not work anymore

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like non-public artifact - aka not available from Maven Central Repository. https://search.maven.org/

You need to add your private repo that hold given artifact - maybe company's artifactory?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a dependency declared for that library in your pom.xml. However, when you try to build your project, it can't find the jar in your repo.

I don't see that artifact on maven central, so you might be using a private mirror for maven central, which you'll see this at the top of your main pom. If that's the case, you may not be able to reach your private mirror because you are not connected to the VPN, or some other networking issue.

Comment: Or dependency part is commited to repository, but repositories part not ;)